# Error in operator function in multimap

Tags: c++, qt, stl

I am trying to create a multimap using multikey structure as a key and I am getting a error described below:

code:

```
struct stCont
{
    long long Tok;
    char Reserved;
    long long Asset;
}
struct MultiKey {

    char InstrumentName[6];
    char Symbol[10];
    long long ExpiryDate;
}
struct myComp
    {
       bool operator() (const MultiKey& lhs, const MultiKey& rhs)
       {
           if((lhs.ExpiryDate==rhs.ExpiryDate)&&(memcmp(lhs.InstrumentName,rhs.InstrumentName,6))&&(memcmp(lhs.Symbol,rhs.Symbol,10)))
           {
               return 1;
           }

           return 0;
       }
    };
std::multimap<MultiKey, stCont,myComp> cont_map;
```

error:

```
expression having type 'const myComp' would lose some const-volatile qualifiers in order to call 'bool myComp::operator ()(const MultiKey &,const MultiKey &)'
```

Comment: Your code compiles fine on ideone ([link](http://ideone.com/SrkqI7)).

Comment: Yes, same [here](http://ideone.com/bHDMQU) 
probably [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t209x37w.aspx) explains your error, which might be occurring because of something else, not shown here

Comment: What if you make your operator() const? `bool operator() (const MultiKey& lhs, const MultiKey& rhs) const`

Comment: the error coming in release mode at the time of compiling but in debugging mode no error is showing in compiling.it is coming at runtime,if I am using cont_map variable.

Comment: @Rsvay this is a side question here, when bool operator() is used in multimap and what is its function. sorting the multimap ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should rewrite the multimap code like this and remove the mycomp structure:

```
struct MultiKey {

    char InstrumentName[6];
    char Symbol[10];
    long long ExpiryDate;


    bool operator< (const MultiKey& lhs)const
    {
        if((lhs.ExpiryDate==ExpiryDate)&&(memcmp(lhs.InstrumentName,InstrumentName,6))&&(memcmp(lhs.Symbol,Symbol,10)))
                   {
                       return true;
                   }

                   return false;
    }


};
```

Comment: In general, it is encouraged to write operators as free functions (friend, if necessary).

Comment: And you might want to change the comparison logic to match the name (`operator<`). This does an equality comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just write just write `operator <` for `MultiKey`?  Or you'll have to change `myComp` because it isn't what `multimap` wants anyway (it wants a less-than comparison).

Answer (score 1):

Look at the The C++11 Standard, `§23.4.5.1` and the header:

```
template <class Key, class T, class Compare = less<Key>,
    class Allocator = allocator<pair<const Key, T> > >
class multimap {
public:
    // ...
    class value_compare {
        friend class multimap;
    protected:
        Compare comp;
        value_compare(Compare c) : comp(c) { }
    public:
        typedef bool result_type;
        typedef value_type first_argument_type;
        typedef value_type second_argument_type;

        bool operator()(const value_type& x, const value_type& y) const {
            return comp(x.first, y.first);
        }
    };
    // ...
};
```

The comparison function as defined by `class value_compare` is `const`. Now, I may be misinterpreting the standard, but this definition seems to be invalid if the `operator()` is non-`const` in class `Compare`.

As to why does it work for some people... Perhaps some finer points about instantiation rules prevent this from being an error, or the implementations are not requierd to adhere strictly to the type definitions in the standard; if so, I'd be glad if someone more versed with The Standard could clarify.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the compile error, declare the comparison function to be a `const` member:

```
bool operator() (const MultiKey& lhs, const MultiKey& rhs) const
                                                           ^^^^^
```

Then you have another problem: the comparator needs to perform a "less than" comparison, but yours does an equality comparison. You want something like

```
if (lhs.ExpiryDate < rhs.ExpiryDate) return true;
if (lhs.ExpiryDate > rhs.ExpiryDate) return false;
if (memcmp(lhs.InstrumentName,rhs.InstrumentName,6) < 0) return true;
if (memcmp(lhs.InstrumentName,rhs.InstrumentName,6) > 0) return false;
if (memcmp(lhs.SymbolName,rhs.SymbolName,10) < 0) return true;
return false;
```

You may find it more convenient to overload `operator<` rather than defining a named comparator type, so that you can use `std::multimap<MultiKey, stCont>` with the default comparator.